# get specific sub string form raw condition

Tags: regex

I want to have a regex formula with will capture only the **BOLD** section of the following strings:

**variable.subvariable.subvariable2[0].subvariable3.subvariable4.subvariable5** === 'H'
**variable.subvariable.subvariable2[0].subvariable3.subvariable4.subvariable5** === 'M'

(**variable.subvariable.subvariable2[0].subvariable3.subvariable4.subvariable5** === 'H' || **variable.subvariable.subvariable2[0].subvariable3.subvariable4.subvariable5** === 'M')

**variable.subvariable.subvariable2[0].subvariable3. subvariable4.subvariable5**.includes('H')

'H'.includes(**variable.subvariable.subvariable2[0].subvariable3. subvariable4.subvariable5**)

This string "**variable.subvariable.subvariable2[0].subvariable3. subvariable4.subvariable5**" is a placeholder. The condition should capture any generic string and exclude the rest of the sentence/condition.

Regex Magic fairy please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
[a-z\d]+\.[a-z\d]+\.[a-z\d]+\[[\d]+\]\.[a-z\d]+\.[a-z\d]+\.[a-z\d]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/g09CKM/1